# Understanding "missing method body" error

Tags: java

I would like to pass an arraylist "test" into a method "sortArray" and return it but I keep getting errors. Here is my code, please can you help?

I am getting the following error "missing method body"

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SortingArrayListSD
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    ArrayList<Integer> test = new ArrayList<>();
    Random r = new Random();

    int largest = 0, indexnumber = 0;

    for ( int s = 0 ; s < 10; s++ )
    {
      test.add(1 + r.nextInt(99));
    }

    System.out.println("ArrayList Before: " + test);
    test = SortArray(test);
    System.out.println("ArrayList After: " + test);
  }

  public static ArrayList<Integer> SortArray( ArrayList<Integer> test );
  {
    ArrayList<Integer> test = new ArrayList<>();
    for ( int s = 1; s<test.size(); s++ )
    {
      for ( int a = 0; a<test.size(); a++)
      { 
        if ( test.get(s) > test.get(a) )
        {
          int temp = test.get(s);
          test.set(s, test.get(a));
          test.set(a, temp);
        }
      }
    }
    return test;
  }
}
```

Comment: both the parameter and the local variable are called `test`..

Comment: **public static ArrayList<Integer> SortArray( ArrayList<Integer> test );**

Remove the semicolon from end of the method.

Also, change **ArrayList<Integer> test = new ArrayList<>();**
 to 
 test = new ArrayList<>();

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `;` on this line:

`public static ArrayList<Integer> SortArray( ArrayList<Integer> test );`

Also, you should respect Java code conventions. Your `SortArray` method, for example, should be named `sortArray`.

You can take a look at [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), or for a more practical approach you can take a look at [Google Java Style](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html).

Anyway, you might want to study [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) (in particular, in your case http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/algorithms/index.html#sorting could be of help)

Comment: thank you so much I apologise for makıng thıs mıstake and thank you for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Rename the method local ArrayList variable test, it will conflict with the one passed in parameter.

Comment: A good point, but not the cause of the error that the question asks about.

Comment: @IanRoberts Actual cause was already answered I pointed out another error.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the parameter or method local variable.
Better option is to use Collections.sort method for sorting.

Comment: A good point, but not the cause of the error that the question asks about.